# CSS: Circular Image

Tags: css

I am trying to make an image circular but it does not look to be a perfect circle after-all, here is a snippet of my code and a link showing the result

```
#aboutme{
 padding: 150px;
}

#aboutme img{
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 0;
 width: 150px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 float:left;
 padding: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}
```

This is what happens: https://gyazo.com/92f967809fc4dea91a8a5cbaabf8d087

Comment: I don't actually see any of your css being applied to the profile image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Padding is included in the calculation, as is everything inside the border-box. Using `margin` instead of `padding`, it won't be inside the border-box, resolving your issue.

Answer (score 0):

For a perfect circle to form, you need the width to equal to the height, so the hackie way of `border-radius: 50%;` for shaping circle would work properly.

```css
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.perfect {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.weird1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 83px;
}

.weird2 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<img class="perfect"></br>
<img class="weird1"></br>
<img class="weird2"></br>
```